# How to apply .filter operator on individual elements of a CurrentValueSubject that's an array in Swift Combine?

Tags: swift, swift5, combine

I have a `CurrentValueSubject` that's an array of `ChatModelFirebase`. What I want to do is remove all `ChatModelFirebase` models that have a status field of "canceled". The issue is that when I apply `.filter(..)` operator it's acting on the entire array and not the individual items.

```
var chatFirebaseModels: CurrentValueSubject<[ChatModelFirebase], Never> = CurrentValueSubject([])

chatFirebaseModels
    .filter({ (chatModelFireBaseArray) -> Bool in
        // I want individual array items, not chatModelFireBaseArray
        return false
    })
```

Here is what code completion looks like:

[image]

You can see that `.filter(..)` is being applied to the `[ChatModelFirebase]` array and not the individual `ChatModelFirebase` models.

Is the answer here to just use `.flatMap(..)`? I am curious if there is a right way of using `.filter(...)`, hence my question.

Comment: It depends, do you want to keep the array and filter elements within their own array? -> use `.map { $0.filter { ...} }`. Want to filter all induvidual elements? -> use `flatMap { $0 }.filter { ... }`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. The goal is to remove some of the items in the array that do not match a certain boolean condition.

Comment: My question is about the result of your mapping + filtering. Do you want to end up with `[ChatModelFirebase]` (like you suggested yourself in your question by using flatmap) or `[[ChatModelFirebase]]` (map + filter). Both ways are "correct" in a sense that they accomplish the same in the end, but the resulting type will be different.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just want to end up with an array of models i.e. `[ChatModelFirebase]`.

Answer (score 12):

You can either use `.map` to return a filtered array:

```
chatFirebaseModels
    .map { array in
       array.filter { element in
          // ... filter by element
       }
    }
```

Or use a pure-Combine chain (though, seems unnecessarily complicated):

```
chatFirebaseModels
   .flatMap { Publishers.Sequence(sequence: $0) }
   .filter { element in
      // ... filter by element
   }
   .collect()
```

Comment: is it ok when you split one publisher into many publishers and combine them back into array? What about big arrays?